# 12M Rolling Active Customers

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, presto, data-lake, exasol

I have a order table with `order_date` and `customer_id` fields and for each date in 2022 and beyond I want to compute the 12 month rolling distinct active customers using SQL.

I've tried

```sql
SELECT
  order_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) OVER (ORDER BY order_date RANGE INTERVAL '360' day PRECEDING) AS customers_12m
  -- using a window function to create a 360d frame to count distinct customers during that time period
FROM
  orders
WHERE
  order_date >= '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY
  order_date
HAVING
  order_date >= '2022-01-01'
```

Somehow I having a problem with different errors (distinct not supported, range not supported, etc.) based on different DBMS platforms (Redshift, Exasol, Trino (Presto)). Can someone please guide me if this is possible to achieve using just SQL?

Sample Input

| order_date | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | X |
| 2023-01-01 | Y |
| 2023-01-02 | X |
| 2023-01-03 | X |
| 2023-01-04 | Z |
| 2023-01-05 | Z |

Sample Output

Instead of 360 days, assume 1 day here

| order_date | customers_1d |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2 (X and Y) |
| 2023-01-02 | 2 (X and Y) |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 (X only) |
| 2023-01-04 | 2 (X and Z) |
| 2023-01-05 | 1 (Z only) |

Comment: So which out of that list of DBMSs are you actually using? Also, can you update your question with a sample result that you are trying to achieve - your current SQL seems to suggest that you want a count of customers placing orders on every individual date?

Comment: We have the datasource in exasol, redshift, datalake (via trino, presto), solution for anyone of them will work me. I have included the sample @NickW

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn’t this give you what you want?

```
SELECT
  order_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)
FROM
  orders
WHERE
  order_date >= '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY
  order_date
```

Comment: It only shows the customers shopping at that specific date, not rolling 12 months